# What is the real number of questions?

Tags: support, questions, statistics, stackexchange.com

According to https://stackexchange.com/sites there are 10931 (by now) questions on travel, but according to https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions  there are only 10915. Why there is a difference and what is the real number of questions on that site?

The question is about Travel.SE but I assume it's also valid for all other Stackexchange sites.

---

Some hours later the global list shows 10936 questions and Travel.SE shows 10919 questions, so it cannot be just a cache issue.

Comment: IIRC SE itself isn't as up-to-date in stats as the sites themselves. The question is, why are the questions lesser on Travel.SE than the last few hours/day?

Comment: @MARamezani deleted questions - e.g. off topic, spam. 16-17 of those per several hours is quite possible.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yup, but didn't wanna make assumptions.

Comment: *It's always caching*

Answer (score 4):

This is the same for Meta SE here. The site list shows 71,036 questions, while the [question page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions) shows 71,037. It seems your question didn't get though yet.

I blame the cache.

Comment: first of all the difference for Travel is much bigger (16 questions - it's around the number of questions asked by day) and the qustion page shows more questions than travel.se

Comment: @Dirty-flow: Probably deleted questions, which don't get included in the count.

Comment: We have way more than 16 deleted questions on travel....but fewer than that get deleted per day...

Comment: @MarkMayo: I indeed meant that was today only (or at least since the last update). Are you sure less are deleted per day? It doesn't seem an awful lot.

Comment: On travel.SE? Fairly sure, I've been there since the beginning, and we only get 15-16 questions a day as it is.  Although it's just occurred to me that closed questions getting cycled out would be included, that may account for it to some extent...

Answer (score 4):

This difference between the global [Stack Exchange sites' list](https://stackexchange.com/sites) and the singular counts in each site is probably caused by the different frequency of update: on a single site (e.g. [Travel.SE](http://travel.stackexchange.com)) the accuracy of the questions/answers count is more important than in the global chart, where these numbers only give you an overview. Therefore **the global site list is updated less frequently than the single lists in each site, which need to be updated in real time**, causing inconsistent counts.

I.E. the "global" sites' list update may show more or less questions depending on the number of deleted/created questions in a certain update interval.

Comment: yeah, but the global site list shows more questions and not less.

Comment: @Dirty-flow that's because many questions are often closed/removed after the global update. The global update may show more or less questions depending on the number of deleted/created questions in a certain update interval.

Comment: that cannot be the (only) reason - the count of both is updated but there is still a difference (10936 to 10919)